# How to prepare a variable asynchronously (get it from DB) in keystonejs before keystone start?

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

I have a keystone model that I want some data to be ready before using `keystone.add`, I want this data for `options` for a select field: `type: Types.Select`.

This is what I tried:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;
let getCategories= require('./Category').getCategories; // THIS IS ASYNC

Post.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true, initial: true },
    category: {
        type: Types.Select,
        required: true,
        initial: true,
        options: getCategories(),
     }
});
```

But this gives me this error: `Select fields require an options array`. Obviously, it's because  I am getting `categories` asynchronously here and it is not ready yet!  How can I prepare categories before keystone start? I tried middleware but got multiple errors.

**Update:** 
Also tried this with no chance:

```
let getCats = async function(){
   let result = await getCategories();
   return results;
}

Post.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true, initial: true },
    category: {
        type: Types.Select,
        required: true,
        initial: true,
        options: getCats(),
     }
});
```

Comment: You could consider using a [Relationship field](https://keystonejs.netlify.com/documentation/database/relationships/) to populate a selection using another model.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your `GoodSchema` code to wait before getting categories for that you need to make a `async` function to `await` for your categories like
Below function will be added to your `./Category`

```
function getCategories(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
   resolve(['a','b']);
  })
}
```

and you will call your categories like this

```
var cats = await getCategories()
console.log(cats)
```

Comment: I am using promise inside getCategories function. The problem is that the entire file s rendered during keystone init.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: You should have your `getCats` and `Post.add` function in the same block either call `Post.add` in the `getCats` function or create another function to call both of them in it

Comment: I know what you mean but it's not possible,  keystone does not wait for it and does not register the list if I do that